# Box getting shifted from its place

Tags: html, css

I have some boxes in HTML but one of the boxes is getting shifted from its place. Here is [JsBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/aLOJiLi/1/edit)

#### HTML

```
<div id="summary">
    <div class="box"><span>Average fill time</span></div>
    <div class="box"><span>Listing</span></div>
    <div class="box"><span>Archive</span></div>
    <div class="box"><span>Views</span></div>
    <div class="box"><span>Submissions</span></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.box {
  height: 60px;
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

PS: I know this is happening due to three words in the box. Setting `overflow-y: hidden` fix this problem. But I want to know why is this happening at first place ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example code : http://jsbin.com/elOdOpa/1/edit

Add `vertical-align: top` to your `.box` elements (since vertical alignment is `baseline` by default and the current alignment is shown as in the picture below

[image]

Comment: Impressive solution +1. Can you please tell me the cause of problem as well.

Comment: Opps delete that comment. Its your text in the first box. Its two rows.

Comment: Ah there we go the answerer has explained in the answer. +1.

Answer (score 1):

You could change `display:inline-block;` to `float:left;`.

[<kbd>JSBin</kbd>](http://jsbin.com/EsOruqOP/1/edit)

Comment: I agree with this one. As I see no reason for it to be `display: inline-block`. +1